# error in nops_eval 'register' does not contain all columns registration/name/id

Tags: r-exams

I am trying to use the nops_eval function like this:

```
eval <- nops_eval(register = "nops_eval/pauta.csv",
          solutions = "nops_eval/Ex_AEI_MTI_v.rds",
          scans = "nops_eval/nops_scan_20210712161737.zip",
          language = "pt",
          eval = exams_eval(partial = F, negative = -.25,rule = "false"),
          dir = "eval",
          mark = F,
          file = "exame_M2_ep_rec",
          results = "nops_eval_M2rec",
          interactive = T)
```

My register file is a csv with semi-colon separated values:

[image]

But I am getting this error:

`Error in nops_eval(register = "nops_eval/pauta.csv", solutions = "nops_eval/Ex_AEI_MTI_v.rds",  : 'register' does not contain all columns registration/name/id`

That I can't really explain. I am running Rstudio on Windows 10.

Any idea of what may be causing the non-recognition of "registration;name;id"?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this looks strange. Maybe some mismatch in the file path or some other detail. Please check `x <- read.csv2("nops_eval/pauta.csv", colClasses = "character")`, specifically `names(x)`. Is this the intended file with the intended column names `"registration"`, `"name"`, `"id"`?

Comment: Thanks Achim,
Yes, there's a problem:

 > names(x)
[1] "ï..registration" "name"            "id"

But, I can see why the "registration" field becames "ï..registration"...

Comment: Sometimes csv files can have a weird non-ASCII symbol at the beginning of the first line that is not visible depending on the editor with which it is viewed. You can try to delete the entire first line and then re-write it by hand.

Comment: Thanks Achim. Ok, this is what I did: renamed the column names with ```names(x)<-c("registration", "name", "id") and resaved the x df with write.csv2... It worked...

Comment: OK, I've combined the notes above into a proper answer so that you can accept it and others that have the same (or similar) problems can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason must be that when read into R the data has different column names. To check this "by hand" you can use

```
x <- read.csv2("nops_eval/pauta.csv", colClasses = "character")
names(x)
## [1] "registration" "name"         "id"
```

This is what `nops_eval()` uses internally. Possibly, the problems are created by the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) added by some software packages (notably Excel) at the beginning of CSV files to signal how they were stored. Depending on the locale settings these may lead to hiccups and unwanted characters when reading the header line of the CSV.

To work around such problems it's best to fix the header line and re-save the CSV file, e.g., using `write.table()` or `write.csv2()` in R.